# Scheme max on sub lists

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

I've written a function to get the maximum value from a list of nested lists, I have the general form of the function down right; it works on flat lists and nested lists but seems to fail when there are sibling nested lists.

Here is my code:

```
(define (multi-max array)
  (cond
    ((null? array) 0)
    ((number? (car array))
      (if (> (car array) (multi-max (cdr array)))
       (car array)
       (multi-max (cdr array))))
    ((pair? (car array))
     (multi-max (car array)))
    (else
     (multi-max (cdr array)))))
```

Here is a test list that it fails on: `(multi-max '(1 9 83 9 (332 (334) (2 3 4224))))`

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, logically, some help would be nice!

Comment: This problem is absolutely begging for the application of the Design Recipe (cf. http://www.htdp.org/ ). Specifically: what's the data definition for your input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't locate the logical error so I rewrote it in a *more* recursive way :)
It's important to identify the recursive parts first before writing our function.

`multi-max` can be defined recursively as `multi-max = max(multi-max(car), multi-max(cdr))`

```
(define (multi-max array)
  (cond ((pair? array) (max (multi-max (car array)) (multi-max (cdr array))))
        ((number? array) array)
        (else 0)))
```

`(multi-max '(1 9 83 9 (332 (334) (2 3 4224))))`
 now outputs `4224`.

**Edit:** Ok, I think I found the error:

```
...
((pair? (car array))
 (multi-max (car array)))
(else
 (multi-max (cdr array))))
...
```

The code ignores the `(cdr array)` in the `(pair? )` part and `(car array)`
in the `(else  )` part.

It should be:

```
(else (max (multi-max (car array)) (multi-max (cdr array))))
```

(*) note that the `(pair?  )` is removed.